# Swift: using the value of a ui element in a dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, exc-bad-access, swift, xcode6

I have a dictionary params as below

```
var params : Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = [
 "name"          :   self.name.text
]
```

I can assign self.name.text to a variable and see it has a value.

but when i do

```
 println(params)
```

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at runtime

i can fix it with "as String" as below

```
var params : Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = [
    "name"          :   self.name.text as String
]
```

Does anyone know why i need the cast to stop the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Is this only the case for UI elements?  Does this also happen for properties of non-UI objects?

Comment: What if you declare your dictionary as Dictionary<String,String> ?

Comment: i can declare a property of my controller class and assign that to the value of name without an exception

Comment: Dictionary<String, String> works which is interesting, however i need this dictionary to also contain Doubles

Comment: another way is to cast on println ... try `println(String(params))`

Comment: if i put literal values in instead of ones coming from a ui field it works fine and prints as expected, same if i use a property of the class.

Comment: It probably has something to do with a UITextField's text property being optional. Possibly a bug in the compiler, wouldn't be the first I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `print` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printing.html):

> The value you supply for object must conform to the Printable or DebugPrintable protocol:

So I would expect that `NSString` does not conform to any of these protocols.

The following code also generates the same error

```
var str = NSString()
println(str as String) // fine
println(str) // fails
```

Comment: This certainly looks like the answer, but do you know why according to Xcode: UIKit/UITextField the text property is a String!